# CakePHP / Facebook Plugin - Logout button linking to #

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook, cakephp-1.3

I'm attempting to use the Facebook plugin with CakePHP - all seems like it's going well - I can use the like/recommend buttons - I can login via facebook - it asks for permission for things that I told it to...etc

The problem is, my LOGOUT button just links to whatever page you're on plus a #

So - if I'm on index.php, the logout button links to index.php#

I AM including the correct facebook html tag and init() in the correct locations.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code for the logout button:

```
if(!$session->check('Auth.User.id') && !$this->Connect->user('id')) {
    echo $this->Html->link('LOGIN', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
} else {     
    echo $facebook->logout(array('redirect' => array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'logout'), 'label' => 'LOGOUT'));
}
```

---

**EDIT**

And to be clear - I wouldn't care if the link is a #, but the logout button does nothing at all except bump the browser up to the top.  It doesn't log out, it doesn't refresh the page.

---

**EDIT2**

If I start a fresh browser, login into Facebook, then go to my site, it auto-logs me in - at that point, the logout button works perfectly.  But - if I log-in via a user-login on my site (instead of FB), the logout button just pops me to the top of the page (ie - the empty anchor link)

Comment: I have the same problem but only with Firefox (v3.6) and IE. Chrome works well. I haven't found a solution yet but this helps me a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563539/cakephp-facebook-plugin-webtechnick-only-share-working Did you find a solution Dave?

Comment: I haven't - have turned off Facebook login for now - pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently dubugging the same problem (plus 1 other), and what I have found is that the FacebookHelper.php seems to handle $options incorrectly:

```
if((isset($options['redirect']) && $options['redirect']) || $options['custom']){
            $options['redirect'] = Router::url($options['redirect']);
            $onclick = "logout('".$options['redirect']."');";
            if(isset($options['confirm'])){
                $onclick = 'if(confirm("'.$options['confirm'].'")){'.$onclick.'}';
            }
            if($options['img']){
                $source = '/Facebook/img/'.$options['img'];
                return $this->Html->image($source, array(
                'alt' => $options['alt'],
                'id' => $options['id'],
                'url' => '#',
                'onclick' => $onclick));
            }
            else {   /* HERE  */
                return $this->Html->link($options['label'], '#', array(
                    'onclick' => $onclick, 'id' => $options['id']));
            }
        } else {
            $source = '/Facebook/img/facebook-logout.png';
            return $this->Html->image($source, array(
                'alt' => 'Facebook logout',
                'url' => '#',
                'id' => $options['id'],
                'onclick' => 'logout();'));
```

I'm not very expert in PHP, and could be wrong, but it seems that if $options are populated e.g. redirect, but no img param, then no button appears on screen (it goes to 'HERE'). By changing the code above, I can get then face book link displayed and the FB logout works. Now I' debugging an Auth prob where sessions keep regenerating after logout (with no FB connection).

My 'fixed code', still WIP and ugly is:

```
if((isset($options['redirect']) && $options['redirect']) || $options['custom']){
                    debug($options);
        $onclick = "logout('".$options['redirect']."');";
        if(isset($options['confirm'])){
            $onclick = 'if(confirm("'.$options['confirm'].'")){'.$onclick.'}';
        }
        if($options['img']){
            $source = '/Facebook/img/'.$options['img'];
            return $this->Html->image($source, array(
            'alt' => $options['alt'],
            'id' => $options['id'],
            'url' => '#',
            'onclick' => $onclick));
        }
        else {
                        //Yes it gets here!
                        $source = '/Facebook/img/facebook-logout.png';
                        $redirect=$options['redirect'];
                        return $this->Html->image($source, array(
            'alt' => 'Facebook logout',
            //'url' => '#',
                            'url' => $redirect,
            'id' => $options['id'],
            'onclick' => "logout('$redirect');"));
        }
    } else {
        $source = '/Facebook/img/facebook-logout.png';
        return $this->Html->image($source, array(
            'alt' => 'Facebook logout',
            'url' => '#',
            'id' => $options['id'],
            'onclick' => 'logout();'));
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The link should be generated as a "#". The logout function generates this link with a javascript onclick event, which makes the call to FB and logs the user out.  I would check if you're getting javascript errors.  You reference the [source code for confirmation](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/master/views/helpers/facebook.php).

Comment: I'm not getting any javascript errors - the onclick it generates is:  onclick="FB.logout(function(response){ window.location = &#039;/logout&#039;});"

Comment: That's the correct javascript. Try doing the entire authentication and logout process in a clean browser.

Comment: Still nothing - no javascript errors, and it does nothing.  Tried multiple computers, multiple browsers...etc.

Comment: Try constructing the link manually and getting rid of the onClick param, which is what I do: `<a href='#' id='logout_link'>Logout</a><script>$("#logout_link").click(function(){FB.logout(function() { window.location = '/users/logout'; });});</script>`

Comment: Your code does the same thing - just bumps the browser to the top of the page.

Comment: Sorry - realized that was jquery-based.  Do you have that loaded? If so, and you're still getting the same behavior, what happens if you change the link click() function to just call something simple like alert('test')?  Is the code even being run?  Also, is javascript functioning correctly on other parts of the page?

Comment: I do have jquery loaded - when I just do an alert instead of the facebook function, it alerts when the page loads, but then doesn't do anything when I click on the button.

Comment: It alerts when the page loads? That doesn't make sense, assuming it's properly nested in the .click(). Is this what you have? `<a href='#' id='logout_link'>Logout</a><script>$("#logout_link").click(function(){alert('test');});</script>`

Comment: ah - my bad - I had the alert just inside the click instead of inside a function inside the click.  The alert works fine when you click the logout button.

Comment: Ok, that helps.  Are you sure no error is being thrown with the FB.logout() call?  The only reason that the browser would move to the top is if the js isn't triggering or working correctly.

Comment: Getting a few errors, but I don't think they're related:  "Image corrupt or truncated: <unknown>" - I get this when I go to Facebook too though.  More importantly, I narrowed down WHEN the logout button doesn't work - see "EDIT2" above.  I'm also getting a "Message" - www.facebook.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555   Not sure if that's at all related.

Comment: AND - every once in awhile after logging in/out trying to logout...etc.  When I refresh the page, it gets stuck in an auto-refresh loop.  My guess is (just a guess) that it's auto-login/logout loop of some kind?

Comment: It sounds like you need to detect whether the user is logged in via FB connect or your own login mechanism.  If they're not logged in via FB connect, the link should just point to '/users/logout' or whatever.